# In which folder / directory does SQL 2008 store files?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Where can I set the folder to store a database in when I create a new Database in the Microsoft SQL 2008 Server?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Via the GUI, right click the main server node:

[image]

Programmatically, it is stored in the registry. You can see this here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/sqlman/archive/2009/07/20/tsql-script-determining-default-database-file-log-path.aspx

However, you'd typically specify paths, names, sizes etc in your CREATE DATABASE

Answer (score 0):

For clarification from gbn's answer, if you want to designate the locations when you first create the database do it with the CREATE DATABASE command

eg.

```
    CREATE DATABASE [DatabaseName]
     ON  PRIMARY 
    ( NAME = N'PRIMARY', FILENAME = N'F:\MSSQL\Data\PrimaryFile.mdf' , SIZE = 102400KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10240KB ), 
 FILEGROUP [Data] DEFAULT
( NAME = N'BASKET_data1', FILENAME = N'F:\MSSQL\Data\DataFile.ndf' , SIZE = 62914560KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 5242880KB )
     LOG ON 
    ( NAME = N'Acquisition_log', FILENAME = N'E:\MSSQL\Log\logFile.ldf' , SIZE = 83886080KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 5242880KB )
     COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

note that the size of these files is quite large (depending on what you're doing,

Its advisable to have your data and log files on separate drives and I've added in a separate Primary and Data file where DATA is the default file where new tables will be added, (its easier for DR if you there's a problem with the master database and its all in one file without having to worry about the rest of the database).